# HOUR function in Excel

Tags: excel, function, time, types, hour

im trying to get only the hour from time column. for example if the time is 19:16:00 I want to get only 19. for this I tried the formula HOUR but the result i get is 0:00 no matter what the time is.

I tried already to convert the data in the column from text but it didnt change the problem.

what can be the reason for that?

thanks

Comment: may be 19:16:00 is not formatted as a date in your column. The HOUR formula works fine for me

Comment: If you need the value 19 for a calculation, use HOUR(), but if you need to display 19 in the cell without changing its value, format the cell as "hh" (Number > Custom > type "hh" and click OK).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following screenshot:

[image]

The formula in both cells in column B is the same:

```
=HOUR(A1)
```

Cell B1 shows `0:00:00` because it is formatted as **time**.

Cell B2 shows `19` because it is formatted as **General**.

If you see `0:00` as the result, then your result cell is formatted as time. Change the format to General to see the number.

You need to understand that time is stored in Excel as a decimal. For example, 6 am is stored as 0.25. If that is formatted as time, it shows as `6:00`.

If you extract the hour from a time value, the result is an integer, in this example, the result is `19`.

That integer value does not have any decimals, so if it is formatted as time, the `19` will not show (since time formats ignore what's before the decimal point), and since there are no decimals in the number, the time will show as 0:00.

When you extract the hour from a time value, that formula cell must be formatted with General to show the hour as an integer.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer that realy helped to understand better how excel works!

Comment: If that helped, please mark the post as the answer, as explained in the [Tour]. That's how you can say thanks around here.